# Is $4^{x+6}-3$ an algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$4^{x+6}-3$$

Can we say this is an algebraic expression? I believe it is an *exponential* expression, but is it also an *algebraic* expression?

Comment: Unless you restrict $x$ to be a rational number, $4^{x + 6} - 3$ is not an [algebraic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression) since exponents in algebraic expressions must be rational numbers.

Answer (score -1):

"In mathematics, an algebraic expression is an expression built up from integer constants, variables, and the algebraic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and exponentiation by an exponent that is a rational number)." [[Wikipedia: Algebraic expression]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression)

According to this definition, $4^{x+6}-3$ is not an algebraic expression - because the integer constants ($3,4,6$) and the variables ($x$) are connected in the expression with help of non-algebraic operations. $()^x$ is not an algebraic operation, because transcendental (= non-algebraic) operations are needed, e.g.: $a^x=e^{x\ln(a)}$.

But a completely different question is, if the value of the expression is algebraic (an algebraic number) or not.

An exponential expression is a mathematical expression that contains an exponent that is a non-rational expression of the considered variables.

According to this definition, $4^{x+6}-3$ is an exponential expression.

Remember that exponentiation by an exponent that is a rational number is an algebraic operation, but exponentiation by an exponent that is not a rational number is a non-algebraic operation.